# Intellij ScalaTest with Mockito, test framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, mockito, scalatest

I used ScalaTest and Mockito in the test. If I used command line the test passed. But when I run using Intellij got following error. It seems only for the test has mockito imported.

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings.getSerializableMode()Lorg/mockito/mock/SerializableMode; 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings.getSerializableMode()Lorg/mockito/mock/SerializableMode;
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.AcrossJVMSerializationFeature.enableSerializationAcrossJVM(AcrossJVMSerializationFeature.java:166)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:46)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
    at org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar$class.mock(MockitoSugar.scala:74)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, still have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem with Eclipse, and it was because I had multiple instances of the org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings class. This class is present in mockito-core.jar and also in mockito-all.jar. I do not why started to fail, I was using the same configuration for long time and lot of tests, but the thing is that I had to remove from pom.xml the mockito-core dependency and keep only mockito-all. Hope it helps.
PS: you could also run mvn dependency:tree to check if another dependency is also bringing mockito-core.jar

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the method named `getSerializableMode()` in the `MockCreationSettings`class. It seems there is a mismatch between your Mockito and PowerMock version.

Try going through Maven repository for your PowerMock and check which version of Mockito your powermock-api-mockito  depends on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ ultimate 2019.3, scala 2.12.8. I was facing the same issue.

And upgrading the libraries worked for me. Before:

```scala
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.5.12"
"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala-scalatest" % "1.5.12"
```

After:

```scala
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1"
"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.13.0"
"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala-scalatest" % "1.13.0"
```